# Eureka preferIpAddress: true is not working with spring boot 2.1.3 'Greenwich.RELEASE' '

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Due to some reasons, I want microservices clients to be registered into Eureka with their IP address, instead of host name. 
This is not working even after setting eureka: instance: preferIpAddress: true [yaml given below].
Still eureka display only host names. Anyone faced this type of issue and possible remedy would be really helpful.
Springbootversion : 2.1.3 , Spring cloud - Greenwich Release

**application.yml of microservice instance** Please note the preferIpAddress: true

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  application:
    name: booking
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888,http://localhost:8889

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true  
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    healthcheck:
      enabled: false
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    preferIpAddress: true

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
  security:
   enabled: false
```

**application.yml of Eureka server**

```
spring:
  profiles: localpeer1

eureka:
  server:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka

server:
  port: 8761

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS

---
spring:
  profiles: localpeer2
eureka:
  server:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false  
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

server:
  port: 8762

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
```

Dashboard of Eureka still shows the hostname instead of IP address.

Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: I have the same issue... i'll be back if I find the solution...